# Visual C#, DataGridView событие CellValueChanged ограничение ввода символов

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Доброго времени суток. Как в **DataGridView** через событие **CellValueChanged** сделать ограниченный ввод символов в ячейках столбца в котором в данный момент находится курсор?
Номер столбца можно найти следующим образом 
**int yh;
        yh = DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;**
Но как дальше ограничить ввод символов?

Comment: Пробовал через другое событие, но не работает:  private void teacherDataGridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            int yh;
            yh = teacherDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            if ((yh == 1) || (yh == 2) || (yh == 3))
            {
                char l = e.KeyChar;
                if ((l < 'А' || l > 'я') && l != '\b' && l != '.')
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697517/how-to-handle-keyevents-in-a-datagridviewcell) ты можешь узнать как это сделать,

Comment: johnybond32, спасибо